# Existence of a distinguished continuous version of the logarithm of a continuous function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, functional-equations, levy-processes

Let $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space and $\varphi\in C^0(E,\mathbb C\setminus\{0\})$ with $\varphi(0)=1$.

> I want to show that there is an unique $\psi\in C^0(E,\mathbb C)$ with $\psi(0)=0$ and $$\varphi=e^\psi\tag1.$$

If $E=\mathbb R^d$ for some $d\in\mathbb N$, a proof of this claim can be found in [*Lévy Processes and Infinitely Divisible Distributions* by Sato](https://www.cambridge.org/de/academic/subjects/statistics-probability/probability-theory-and-stochastic-processes/levy-processes-and-infinitely-divisible-distributions?format=HB&isbn=9780521553025) (Lemma 7.6). As far as I can see, the proof given there should generalize to the setting of this question.

However, I've read that we can also show the claim by using the results provided in [*Foundations of Modern Analysis* by Dieudonneé](https://www.sciencedirect.com/bookseries/pure-and-applied-mathematics/vol/10/part/P1) (Appendix IX.2), which I will briefly reproduce:

Let $f\in C^0(E,U)$, where $U:=\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|=1\}$. Say $f$ is **inessential** if $f=e^{{\rm i}g}$ for some $g\in C^0(E,\mathbb R)$; otherwise it is called **essential**.. It's easy to see that

1. if $f$ is inessential, then $1/f=\overline f$ is inessential;
2. if $f_i$ are inessential, then $f_1f_2$ is inessential;
3. if $f_1$ is essential  and $f_2$ is inessential, then $f_1f_2$ and $f_1/f_2$ are essential.

Moreover, any $f\in C^0(E,U)$ with $f(E)\ne U$ is inessential. And if $f_i\in C^0(E,U)$ satisfy $f_1(x)\ne-f_2(x)$ for all $x\in E$ and $f_1$ is inessential (resp. essential), then $f_2$ is inessential (resp. essential).

And last but not least, if $E$ is compact and $f\in C^0(E\times[0,1],S^1)$ is such that $E\ni x\mapsto f(x,0)$ is inessential (resp. essential), then $E\ni x\mapsto f(x,1)$ is inessential (resp. essential).

He particularly concludes that any continuous function from a closed ball in $\mathbb R^d$ into $U$ is inessential.

> How are we able to show the desired claim using these results? I can't see how we need to apply them.

Just in case it is important: I've read that we can use the results of Dieudonneé instead of the result of Sato in a footnote referenced in the proof of Corollary 2.5 of [these lecture notes](https://www.math.tu-dresden.de/sto/schilling/sources/papers/schilling-barcelona.pdf#page=16). The author doesn't mention it, but maybe it's important that the setting considered there is $E=\mathbb R^d$ and $$\varphi(t)=\int\mu({\rm d}x)e^{{\rm i}\langle t,\:x\rangle}\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in\mathbb R^d$$ for some probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R^d$ (this can be generalized to $E$ being the dual of a $\mathbb R$-Banach space $\tilde E$ and $\mu$ being a probability measure on $\tilde E$).

This particular choice of $\varphi$ satisfies $$\inf_{t\in\overline B_r(0)}\varphi(t)>0\;\;\;\text{for all }r>0\tag2.$$ In light of the result about about closed balls in $\mathbb R^d$ mentioned above, this might be relevant. But again, I don't see how it could be used to show the desired claim. But if it's really the crucial ingredient, I'd be interested in generalizing it to more general spaces then $\mathbb R^d$. The only crucial property which of the closed balls in $\mathbb R^d$ which is being used should be the compactness.

Answer (score 1):

The result (1) follows from the lifting property of *covering spaces*: Consider $f=\varphi/|\varphi|: E\to S^1$ and the standard covering map $p:\mathbb R\to S^1$, $t\mapsto e^{it}$. Since Banach space are path connected, locally path connected, and simply connected (the fundamental group is trivial) it follows from Proposition 1.33 in Allan Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology* (which is freely available on his homepage) that $f$ has a unique *lift* $g:E\to \mathbb R$ with $g(0)=1$, which means $f=p\circ g$. Then $\psi=\log(|\varphi|)+ig$ satisfies $e^\psi=\varphi$.

The compactness argument you mention will not easily carry over to infinite dimensional Banach spaces which are never locally compact.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm actually aware of the proof you're describing. My main interest is really how the claim can be proved using the results of Dieudonneé. Do you've got any thoughts on that as well?

Comment: The compactness is heavily used in the proof that a continuous map which is homotopic to an inessential one is itself inessential: You need *uniform* continuity of the homotopy $f(t,x)$ to get $|f(t,x)-f(s,x)|$ small uniformly in $x\in E$ if $|s-t|$ is small enough. In the concrete case you would like to apply this with $f(t,x)=\varphi(tx)$ (or $\varphi(tx)/|\varphi(tx)|$) and hence, the *global argument* only seems to work under additional assumptions on $\varphi$.